# How to properly implement nested forms with Validator and Control Value Accessor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my application, I have a need for a reusable nested form component, such as **Address**. I want my `AddressComponent` to deal with its own FormGroup, so that I don't need to pass it from the outside. 
At Angular conference ([video](https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8?t=1522), [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTS20UdnMGqA3ecrv7ww_7CDKQM8VgdH2tbHl94aXgEsYQ2cyjq62ydU3e3ZF_BaQ64kMyQa0INe2oI/pub?slide=id.g293d7d2b9d_1_1532)) Kara Erikson, a member of Angular Core team recommended to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for the nested forms, making the nested form effectively just a `FormControl`.

I also figured out that I need to implement `Validator`, so that the validity of my nested form can be seen by the main form.

In the end, I created the SubForm class that the nested form needs to extend:

```
export abstract class SubForm implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  form: FormGroup;

  public onTouched(): void {
  }

  public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
      this.form.patchValue(value, {emitEvent: false});
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: (x: any) => void): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.form.disable()
      : this.form.enable();
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.form.valid ? null : {subformerror: 'Problems in subform!'};
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
}
```

If you want your component to be used as a nested form, you need to do the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
})

export class AddressComponent extends SubForm {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    super();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      street: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      city: this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

}
```

Everything works well unless I check the validity status of my subform from the template of my main form. In this case `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is produced, see `ngIf` statement ([stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3q4znr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupper%2Fupper.component.html)) :

```
<form action=""
      [formGroup]="form"
      class="main-form">
  <h4>Upper form</h4>
  <label>First name</label>
  <input type="text"
         formControlName="firstName">
         <div *ngIf="form.controls['address'].valid">Hi</div> 
  <app-address formControlName="address"></app-address>
  <p>Form:</p>
  <pre>{{form.value|json}}</pre>
  <p>Validity</p>
  <pre>{{form.valid|json}}</pre>


</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WriteValue will be triggered in the same digest cycle with the normal change detection lyfe cycle hook.

To fix that without using changeDetectionRef you can define your validity status field and change it reactively.

`public firstNameValid = false;`

```
   this.form.controls.firstName.statusChanges.subscribe(
      status => this.firstNameValid = status === 'VALID'
    );
```

`<div *ngIf="firstNameValid">Hi</div>`

Answer (score 5):

Use ChangeDetectorRef

> Checks this view and its children. Use in combination with detach to
>   implement local change detection checks.
>
> > This is a cautionary mechanism put in place to prevent inconsistencies
> >     between model data and UI so that erroneous or old data are not shown
> >     to a user on the page

Ref:https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Ref:https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { Component, OnInit,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upper',
  templateUrl: './upper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upper.component.css']
})
export class UpperComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      address: this.fb.control('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }


}
```

Your Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3q4znr

Comment: thanks! Does it mean that officially recommended way of composing the forms doesn't work and since it relies on a manual change detection call?

Comment: it will work.In your example some how change detection is being triggered after the change detection cycle that is why angular throwing error

Comment: I see that it works, my question is whether or not it's a bug in angular or not?

Comment: Yes, I know this kind of error and how to deal with it. It just surprises me that we need to manually trigger change detection or artificially make the validator asynchronous for such a fundamental operation as decomposition of forms.

Comment: Many developers even view it as a bug. But it’s certainly not. This is a cautionary mechanism put in place to prevent inconsistencies between model data and UI so that erroneous or old data are not shown to a user on the page. Check this also https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: @Chellappanவ is there a way we can access the subform control values while initializing the Upper form? Currently, the Subform values are populated in the Upperform only when we edit the values in the Subform. 

Can we have something like this during initialization?

{
  "firstName": "",
  "address": {
     "street": "",
     "city": ""
   }
}

Comment: You want to get access of all form control inside cva?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes.

Comment: Try inject ControlContainer in your custom form control component it will give access to parent control/

Comment: @Chellappanவ
Looks like there's a confusion. Basically I followed the StackBlitz link provided - stackblitz.com/edit/github-3q4znr, here if you see, initially, the upper form values are just 
{ "firstName": "", "address": "" } which does not contain the subform values. The subform values will get populated in the upper form object only if I type something in it. Is there any way we can have the subform values at the time of initialization? My expectation is can we have the upperform value as -  { "firstName": "", "address": { "street": "", "city": "" } } in the first place itself?

Comment: Yes I understand the issue now let me check

Comment: ChangeDetectorRef worked great, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [hidden] in stand of *ngIf, it will work without ChangeDetectorRef.

Update URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3q4znr-ivtrmz?file=src/app/upper/upper.component.html

```
<div [hidden]="!form.controls['address'].valid">Hi</div>
```